# How can we add a Lock Screen Widget (requiring iOS 16) and still support iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit, lockscreenwidget

How can we add a Lock Screen Widget to an existing Widget Bundle and still support iOS 15? :thinking_face:  for ex this won't compile

```
struct SecondExtraBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        DailyHeartRatesWidget()
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *) {
            LockScreenRecoveryScoreWidget()//Requires iOS 16? 
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this should work. Simply return an `EmptyWidgetConfiguration` in case the widget is not supported.

```swift
struct SomeWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        AlwaysAvailableWidget()
        LockScreenWidget()
    }
}

struct LockScreenWidget: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *) {
            return StaticConfiguration(
                kind: "some.kind",
                provider: LockScreenWidgetTimelineProvider()
            ) { provider in
                Text("Some view")
            }
            .configurationDisplayName("Some display name")
            .description("Some description")
            .supportedFamilies([.accessoryCircular])
        } else {
            return EmptyWidgetConfiguration()
        }
    }
}
```

This did not work before Xcode 14, but [SE-0360](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0360-opaque-result-types-with-availability.md) is already implemented and you can do this now.